# Why doesn't this function change the case of the string when it has a similar character like the first letter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

Can't understand why the following function works for some strings an didn't work for some which has a similar character like the first.

```js
const change = (str,y) => (str.toLowerCase().replace(str[y],str[y].toUpperCase()));

console.log(change('London',3)); //lonDon
console.log(change('Lagos',3)); //lagOs
console.log(change('Germany',3)); //gerMany
console.log(change('Dcoder',3)); //Dcoder 
console.log(change('Bobby',3)); //Bobby
```

Comment: because `.replace(str[y],...)` won't always replace the character at index `y`, it replaces whatever happens to be the first character in the string that's the same as it. That's what's going on in the last 2 of your examples.

Comment: Don't use `.replace()`. Use substrings and concatenation

Comment: Thanks, understood. I could have as well used slice method by splitting first and joining after operation but I was just wondering if replace could perform the magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `String.prototype.replace` replaces the first occurrence when the first argument is a string.

You can split the string change the index to uppercase and finally join the chars.

```js
const change = (str, y) => {
  const lowercase = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  lowercase[y] = str[y].toUpperCase();
  return lowercase.join("");
};

console.log(change('London',3));
console.log(change('Lagos',3));
console.log(change('Germany',3));
console.log(change('Dcoder',3));
console.log(change('Bobby',3));
```

Comment: The initial characters for the last 2 test cases didn't change to lowercases and only the single letter at the defined index should change not all similar characters.

Answer (score 0):

str[3] in "Dcoder" is 'd' and in replace the first charecter is 'D' , so than replaced
you should change code to this:

```
const change = (str,y) => {
str = str.toLowerCase()           
str=str.slice(0,y)+str[y].toUpperCase()+str.slice(y+1)    
return str}
```

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated but the test doesn't require slice method. Replace was the only given option.

Answer (score 0):

Or, in a slightly shortened manner:

```js
const change = (str, n) =>
  str.split("")
     .map((c,i)=>i==n?c.toUpperCase():c.toLowerCase())
     .join("");

['London','Lagos','Germany','Dcoder','Bobby'].forEach(w=>console.log(change(w,3)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works well but sincerely, it's too much for my little brain.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why your function isn't working as expected, but one possible workaround would be to use the built-in string method `upper`:

```
def change_case(s):
    return s.upper()
```

Comment: This uppercases the whole string. He wants to uppercase just the character at index `y`.